# After_udpate rails callback failing test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have an `:after_update` hook to send an email when an order's status is changed.  It seems to fail the following test because `:order_status_id_chaned?` is returning false.

**Test:**

```
context 'when the order_status changes' do
  it 'should send an email' do
    @order2.save
    expect(subject).to receive(:send_confirmation_email)
    @order2.update(order_status_id: 2)
  end
end
```

**Order.rb**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :send_confirmation_email, if: :order_just_submitted? 

  def order_just_submitted?
    p self.order_status_id_changed? # prints false
    p self.is_submitted? # prints true
    self.order_status_id_changed? and self.is_submitted?
  end

  def send_confirmation_email
    ...
  end
end
```

Any idea why `:order_status_id_chaned?` is returning false after updating the value?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I am using v5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order_status_id_changed?` is false at the point it is called, because it is only called after the update. Once the record is saved, the changes are moved into `previous_changes`, so you could do something like:

```
def order_just_submitted?
  previous_changes.keys.include?('order_status_id') && is_submitted?
end
```

In addition, you may want to check what the status was changed to unless you want to trigger an email on any status change.

Comment: thanks, that's what `:is_submitted` checks.  If I changed the `after_update` to `after_update :send_confirmation_email, if: :order_status_id_changed?` that would work?

Comment: No, that would still fail. You need to check previous_changes as I indicated.

Comment: Please update your response.  this actually fails as `previous_changes.keys` returns an array of strings i.e. `["order_status_id", "updated_at"]` and thus `previous_changes.keys.include?(:order_status_id)` is false